# How to access variables of subclass in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class named `Invoices`, and this class contains a list of class `List<MenuInInvoice> menus`. The class `MenuInInvoice` has two variables called `foodName` and `price`.

But in the `main()` class I cannot access these variables.

```
import 'dart:convert';

    import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

    Invoices invoicesFromJson(String str) => 
 Invoices.fromJson(json.decode(str));

    String invoicesToJson(Invoices data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

    class Invoices {
     String orderNo;
     String tableNo;
     String customerName;
     DateTime orderDate;
     List<MenuInInvoice> menus;
     DocumentReference reference;

     Invoices({
      this.orderNo,
      this.tableNo,
      this.customerName,
      this.orderDate,
      this.menus,
     });

     Invoices.fromJson(Map json,{this.reference}){
      orderNo = json["orderNo"] ?? "unknown";
      tableNo = json["tableNo"] ?? "unknown";
      customerName = json["customerName"] ?? "unknown";
      orderDate = DateTime.parse(json["orderDate"]);
      menus = new List<MenuInInvoice>.from(json["menus"].map((x) => MenuInInvoice.fromJson(x)));
     }

     Invoices.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot):
        this.fromJson(snapshot.data, reference: snapshot.reference);


     Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
      "orderNo": orderNo ?? "unknown",
      "tableNo": tableNo ?? "unknown",
      "customerName": customerName ?? "unknown",
      "orderDate": "${orderDate.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0')}-${orderDate.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${orderDate.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}",
      "menus": new List<dynamic>.from(menus.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
  }

   class MenuInInvoice {
    String foodName;
    String price;

    MenuInInvoice({
     this.foodName,
     this.price,
    });

    factory MenuInInvoice.fromJson(Map json) => new MenuInInvoice(
     foodName: json["foodName"] ?? "unknown",
     price: json["price"] ?? "unknown",
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
     "foodName": foodName ?? "unknown",
     "price": price ?? "unknown",
    };
  }
```

Here is my in the main() class:

```
Invoices invoices = new Invoices(
     tableNo: "01",
     orderNo: "001",
     customerName: "Jonh",
     orderDate: DateTime.now(),
     menus.foodName: "abc"
)
```

In the `main()` class I cannot use the statement `menus.foodName` to access variables of class.

How can I do this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve.

The `Invoice` constuctor has five named parameters, one of which is called `menus`.
When you call the constructor, you pass the arguments for the named parameters by writing the parameter name and a colon in front.

In your main code:

```
Invoices invoices = new Invoices(
  tableNo: "01",
  orderNo: "001",
  customerName: "Jonh",
  orderDate: DateTime.now(),
  menus.foodName: "abc"
)
```

you correctly pass arguments to the named parameters `tableNo`, `orderNo`, `customerName` and `orderDate`.

However the syntax `menus.foodname: "abc"` is not valid. There is no parameter named `menus.foodName`, and it is not even a valid name (a single identifier).

Can you describe what you expected/wanted the code to do, because it is not clear from the code you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access foodName directly indeed.

Please try this:

```
List<MenuInInvoice> menuList = List<MenuInInvoice>();
menuList.add(MenuInInvoice(foodName: 'abc'));

Invoices invoices = Invoices(
    tableNo: '01',
    orderNo: '001',
    customerName: 'Jonh',
    orderDate: DateTime.now(),
    menus: menuList);
```